# How do I combine format strings with curly braces in subscript for axis labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subscript, curly-braces

I am trying to use string formatting to insert subscript numbers in axis labels.

I have tried `$_{}$`, however it only works for numbers from 1-9, not for numbers with more than one digit. e.g., 13 becomes subscript 1 and normal 3:

[image]

I know that I must use `_{13}` to have all digits as subscript, but I did not manage to combine this with the `{}` syntax for string formatting.

- I have tried `$_{{}}$` but this just removes all values.
- I have tried `''$_{'{}'}$` which also does not work.

This is my current code:

```
cclib.parser.ccopen('{}'.format(args["input"])).parse() 
axlabels = ["M"] 
for x in range(OmFragDim - 1): 
    label = 'L{}'.format(x + 1) 
    axlabels.append(label)

    ax.set_title('{}$_{}$, {:1.2f} nm'.format(ExS[args["state"] - 1][0], args["state"], stateE), loc='center', y=1.2)
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Can you include some problematic code to clarify your issue? "subscript all values in the title" doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: What's with the `$`s in your syntax? That's not part of Python at all

Answer (score 1):

In the end you want to generate a string containing `"$S_{13}$"` so that it can be rendered by Matplotlib as a simple LaTeX snippet.

To achieve this you could use `"${}_{{{}}}$".format("S", 13)`.

Explanation:

- `.format` will replace any `{}` with each of the arguments.
- Inside a `.format` string you have to use `{{` to escape `{` and `}}` to escape `}` in the output string. This is because otherwise there would be parsing ambiguities.

Comment: Is there any way to that for multiple values, as I have 20 values

Comment: Sure, the number is not limited. If the number is variable, it might be better/cleaner to create a list of strings and then join them at a later time.